# Azure NSG difference between Any and VirtualNetwork for Inbound

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am having trouble understanding default inbound rules in a Network Security Group.

My way of thinking:

- A NSG is applied at a NIC or a subnet level.
- Thus, resources that have their inbound traffic filtered by an inbound rule must be a part of a Virtual Network.

Assuming the above is true, it should not matter if I specify `Any` or `VirtualNetwork` as a destination, as `Any` must be a part of a Virtual Network.

To give a concrete example, take this default rule for traffic from a Load Balancer:

```
Priority:      65001
Name:          AllowAzureLoadBalancerInBound
Port:          Any
Protocol:      Any
Source:        AzureLoadBalancer
Destination:   Any
Action:        Allow
```

Would it make any difference if it was defined with a `VirtualNetwork` destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you are talking about, there is no practical difference between VirtualNetwork and Any for destination. That said the use of the VirtualNetwork tag may make your intention clearer when creating the rule.

The VirtualNetwork rule however is useful when looking at source addresses.